# Does Dynamics NAV 2009 RTC contain orphaned fields?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

Until today, I was under the impression, that a field can only show up in the RTC Layout's dataset, if it has been defined in one of the sections of the classic report.

Then today I was designing a new report and noticed a few dataset fields in the RTC Layout that I could not find in the classic sections.

To verify this, I exported the object as a text file, and searched for the name of the field, as it was appearing in Visual Studio's dataset result:
Sales_Shipment_Header_No_
Sales_Shipment_Line_Document_No_
Sales_Shipment_Line_Line_No_

In the text file of the respective object, I found that these three names where defined in the  section of the file. But did not occur anywhere else. If I searched of the names of other fields, they always had an additional reference in a text field or a label.

I then deleted all occurrences of fields in the dataset, if their names were not referenced by some other object, such as a label or a text field. I confirmed that the search could find no more occurrences of these strings in the file and imported the file in Navision again. To my surprise these fields where still visible in the RTC Layout (I even tried to generate a new layout).

My question: Is this a bug? Or is there some other mechanism at work that generates these fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under NAV 2009 you will get some fields in your dataset that don't appear on your sections. They correspond to the primary key of the table involved.

Example.

Set up a new report using the sales header and sales line tables. Don't add anything to the sections and then design the Layout.  You will have the following fields available
Sales_Header_Document_Type
Sales_Header_No_
Sales_Line Document_No_
Sales_Line_ Document_Type
Sales_Line_Line_No_

Regards

Ian